# From this stemmed my misinterpretation

Tags: word-usage, word-order

*From this stemmed my misinterpretation of the meaning.*

Is this sentence grammatically OK in terms of the word order? Is here inversion possible as in the case of an adverbial expression of place at the beginning on the sentence (*On the table was all the money we had lost*)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your word order here is fine. While the *from* here is not strictly physical, it relies on a physical metaphor, so expression-of-place inversion is perfectly appropriate. (There are no actual physical stems here, either, but we talk about your misunderstanding as it if had a stem, which comes *from* somewhere.)

This inversion sounds slightly more poetic, but it is perfectly correct and understandable:

> The gates of Atlantis stood before me. (ordinary)
>
> Before me stood the gates of Atlantis. (poetic)

---

One side note: "*Is here inversion possible*" should be "*Is inversion possible here*" (or possibly, "*Is inversion here possible*"). Generally, *here* should come after the adjective or verb it modifies.